# django model designing for 3 linked lists

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I planning to design a web-based database in django. In my page, all works of parliamentary questions are automated. Here a sample of table:

[image]

In my input form, many fields will be there including Ministry and Division fields. As per above table, when I select Group 1, all three ministries A,B,C will come to under ministry field as a drop-down lists. Again when I select Ministry A from drop-down, all three Division X,Y,Z will come under the label of Division drop-down list. Note, you may notice all ministry don't have divisions. So when a Ministry don't have division, Division field will be hidden.

To achieve this I am thinking of following models:

```
from django.db import models

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=8, unique=True,
        help_text='A label for URL config.')

class Ministry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=90, unique=True,
        help_text='A label for URL config.')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class Division(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=90, unique=True,
        help_text='A label for URL config.')
    ministry = models.ForeignKey(Ministry)
```

Is it my approach is correct? Any improvement suggestions are welcome.

**Edit:**

django-mptt models:

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Genre(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('genre_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk,})

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

django-mptt output:

```
Group-1
    Ministry A
        Division A
        Division B
        Division C
    Ministry B
    Ministry C
        Division D
        Division E
    Ministry D
Group-2
    Ministry E
        Division G
        Division Z
    Ministry F
        Division I
        Division J
```

But how to make this tree to in-line table as my sample table?

Comment: My opinion is that if there won't be more than these 3 levels, then it's ok.
If this hierarchy can grow, i would use something like nested model.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: @ Milos Miletic, There will be 10 levels and each level will be assigned for a specific date. This will continue cyclically for a duration of a parliament session, nearly 20 working days or working date. I go through your linked page but couldn't understand how it implement in django. Could you give any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I would use one more model such as

```
class MyRecord(models.Model): #please pick a better name
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group')
    ministry = models.ForeignKey('Ministry')
    division = models.ForeignKey('Division', null=True)
```

Now each row will contain the 3 reference to the data...

your table will look this:

ID | Group | Ministry | Division|

1  |  A    |  M1      | D2

2  |  A    |  M2      | D3

2  |  B    |  M2      | D3

and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Couldn't we avoid adding another model by adding 'blank=True' in the name field of Division model?

Comment: @ohid - Maybe so, But I think this is the way to reflect your model since it is the true intent of what you wanted (at least the way I understand :))

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you well from your comment, there will be more levels than these three listed in your question (Group,Ministry,Division).In that case the easiest soultion for you could be to use only one table, in which you will save the name of the group and other attributes and also **parent_id** - id of group that contains it.So it would look something like this:

```
   from django.db import models

   class Group(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
       slug = models.SlugField(max_length=8, unique=True,
        help_text='A label for URL config.')
       parent = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True)
       #Other fields of the model...You could define attributes like
       #level which would define on which level is this group  
       #boolean attribute representing whether this group is leaf element or not and others
```

By doing this you make it possible to have much more that 3 hierarchy levels you defined using 3 tables.
So in this case, all entries would have parent_id assigned to them(except for the top level instances - or in your example Group 1, Group2, Group3)
So for example SQL query for listing all subgroups of 'Group 1' in your example would be:

```
    SELECT g1.name AS level1, g2.name as level2, g3.name as level3
    FROM groups AS g1
    LEFT JOIN groups AS g2 ON g2.parent_id = g1.id
    LEFT JOIN groups AS g3 ON g3.parent_id = g2.id
    WHERE g1.name = 'Group 1';
```

For more info about this approach take a  look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list

The other approach you could use here would be closure tables, you may wanna take a look at this:
http://technobytz.com/closure_table_store_hierarchical_data.html

Hope this helped and best of luck!

Comment: Did you suggesting for use django-mptt. When I use mptt the table structure was changed. Please see my Edit for clarifications.